# qmake: Add uic-generated header files to installation target

Tags: c++, qmake

I am developing a widget library for Linux. It contains some `.ui` files. `.pro` file looks like this:

```
TEMPLATE = lib
SOURCES += ...
HEADERS += ...
FORMS += ...
TARGET = foo
headers.files = $$HEADERS
unix {
    target.path = /usr/lib
    headers.path = /usr/include/foo/
}
INSTALLS += target headers
```

When I’m installing library on system, ui_*.h files are not present in /usr/include/foo/ and this cause compilation error. How do I either remove need to those files or include them in installation target?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'best' solution (IMHO) is to not inherit from the UI classes, but use composition instead. If you use [The Single Inheritance Approach](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/designer-using-a-ui-file.html#the-single-inheritance-approach), you can get by with a forward-declaration of the UI class, thus obviating the need to make its headers publicly visible.